# When I use xlApp.CutCopyMode in my timer my application does not close. Why does this happen?

Tags: c#, excel

I am working on an excel plugin. I am checking if the user is copying anything in excel then the plugin will not run Worksheet.calculate method.

My code is:

```
 if (xlApp.CutCopyMode == 0)
 {
     _activeSheet.Calculate();
 }
```

This code is running inside a timer. When I close excel there is some memory leak. Excel still runs in the background. If I comment 'if (xlApp.CutCopyMode == 0)' then everything works fine. Can anyone explain why does excel has this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. We need to check it in UI thread throw Dispatcher.